# "Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 4 " in magento 2

Tags: product, attributes, backend, magento2.3

While tried to open products via admin end, it throws below error,

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 4

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with id = 4
#0 /var/www/html/xxxx/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/AttributeSetRepository.php(155):
```

DB

[image]
Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted Magento Product default attribute set `Default` that why this error happens. Since at product's attribute set id is **4** and it does not exist that database table `eav_attribute_set` where here all `eav_attribute` set is stored.

As per as, *default magento2*, 4 is the id of default attribute set `Default` of Products`

> And your system does not have that attribute set and but in products
>   `attribute_set_id` is 4.that why this error is happening.

Comment: But in DB, the default attributset is saved with the id 4

Comment: hen how do i create it, but it exists in DB

Comment: But in my system default attributeset is present

Comment: please give screenshot o f `eav_attribute_set`

Comment: I have added the screenshot

Comment: please look,the table ,you see default attribute set id is 11 on your system but at your catalog_product_entity table has attribute has attribute set id s 4

Comment: I guess that you have  tried data migration and seems that you donot migrated the data properly.